# javascript teechart area series top border

Tags: teechart

[image]

Hi guys,

I need to draw area series border only on the top. I attached what I have today.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about hiding chart walls and also axes pen.

Comment: This didn't work. These blue lines are part of the series border, and their size increases with the size of the stroke of the series. We got around it with a line chart on top of an area chart with invisible stroke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest would be to hide the Area pen:

```
areaSeries.format.stroke.fill = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)';
```

and use a Line series to draw the top. Ie:

```
var s = new Tee.Line();
Chart1.addSeries(s);
s.data = areaSeries.data;
s.format.stroke.size = 3;
```